# SSIS Populating Variables using Script Component

Tags: ssis, scripting

New to Script Components, but think I'm heading in the right direction.

I have a flat file made up of a number of Records and each of these have a Type 1,4,5 etc.
I need to store to a variable values from Type 1 (Column 5) and Type 4 (Column 3,5,6) these are then used when writing record Type 5's.

I've started with this scripting component

```
    Public Class ScriptMain
    Inherits UserComponent

    Private Company_Code As String

    Public Overrides Sub PostExecute()
        MyBase.PostExecute()
        Me.Variables.Filter_Company_Code = Company_Code
    End Sub

    Public Overrides Sub Input0_ProcessInputRow(ByVal Row As Input0Buffer)

        If (Row.RecordType = "1") Then
            Company_Code =
        ElseIf (Row.RecordType = "4") Then

        End If
    End Sub

End Class
```

[Example Data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WqIDf.png)

So from the above if Record Type is 1 the Populate the Variable Company_Code with the value from Column 5 of that row highlighted in Yellow.

Then if Record Type 4 will populate variables with the details highlighted in Green.

And when the Record Type is 5 the variables will be added to columns at the end of those records

Hope that makes sense and someone can point me in the right direction.

Thanks
Geoff

Comment: We will be able to better help with sample data and expected output. But short answer is this... If you need results from multiple rows in order to write a record to the data flow, then you need to declare and store the row result outside of row processing.

Comment: I'd also consider using the script component as a source and use var line = File.ReadAllLines(filepath); or read into a stream.

Comment: Hi Keith, sorry only just seen your reply have added an example to my my original post. Thanks Geoff